# Looping a jQuery font-size animation

Tags: jquery, css, animation, loops, font-size

I currently have a line of text that has a default font-size of 24.
I animate this to resize back to 22:

```
$(document).ready(function animateHeader() {
$('#random_header').animate({fontSize : "22px"}, 500);
});
```

I want to loop this animation contineously back and forth from 24 to 22 and 22 to 24.
How can I do this?

Comment: I think the real question is why?...

Comment: You could have this animation in a separate function, and on your last `animate` you call this function again from the starting point. but this is gross, there are other ways to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function animateHeader() {
    $('#random_header').animate({
        fontSize: $('#random_header').css('fontSize') == '24px' ? '22px' : '24px'
    }, 500, animateHeader);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/aDZLy/

Comment: Used the one above, but this one is indeed a lot more compact :)

Answer (score 4):

#### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/uzaweg/2/edit)*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  function animateHeader(){
    $('#random_header').animate({fontSize : 22}, 500,function(){
      $(this).animate({fontSize : 24}, 500, animateHeader);
    });
  }
  animateHeader();
  

});
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
function ani(size){
 $('#random_header').animate({fontSize : size+"px"}, 500, function(){ ani((size==22) ? 24 : 22 ); } );
}

ani(24);
```

Comment: @Sagivo please, use Always™ `===` to compare.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan i disagree. there is no point on === in this case since we don't care if this is a string or int. always use === is a wrong statement.

Comment: don't base your comments on a generated debugger script. you should know that there is a different between === and == in type checking. in this case there is no use for type checking. http://jsfiddle.net/DAzLS/

Comment: I just don't like to scratch my head cause I used somewhere in my 2000+ lines a `==` instead of `===`, And I like to see my code 'validly' debugged. And I don't like to look my code pass through unnecessary conversions before it gets defined.

Comment: Sorry, I just joined Stackoverflow and only got 8 rep ;-(